# Nullability assignment of generic type in kotlin methods

Tags: android, kotlin, generics

I've created this extension method for an `androidx.lifecycle.LiveData`:

```
inline fun <T> LiveData<T>.observeNotNull(crossinline observer: (T) -> Unit) {
    this.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { value ->
        value?.let { observer(it) }
    })
}
```

As you can see, the value passed to the observer parameter (it) can never be null. But when I call this method, the value is technically nullable, as shown in this example:

[image: Example code of observeNotNull extension usage]

I'd like to do something like `crossinline observer: (T!) -> Unit`, is this possible?

EDIT: the extension should work on both nullable and non-nullable livedata types. Preferably combined in 1 extension method, but ifit's only possible when using 2 separate extension methods I'd still like to hear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the concrete type that is represented by type variable `T` if `it` is nullable. If there is no further information to infer the concrete type, it is `Any?`, and thus `it` can be null. You have to define `T: Any` if you want to ensure that `T` represents a non-nullable type:

```
inline fun <T: Any> LiveData<T>.observeNotNull(crossinline observer: (T) -> Unit) {
    this.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { value ->
        value?.let { observer(it) }
    })
}
```

If you want to allow all types for `T`, but not for the argument of `observer`, then this should be possible to achieve with [definitely non-nullable types in Kotlin 1.7](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/whatsnew17.html#stable-definitely-non-nullable-types) using notation `T & Any`:

```
inline fun <T> LiveData<T>.observeNotNull(crossinline observer: (T & Any) -> Unit) {
    this.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { value ->
        value?.let { observer(it) }
    })
}
```

Comment: That second solution is what I was looking for, thanks!